# The value of the parameter must be from -180.0 to 180.0 when getting current geocoordinates in windows phone 8 application

Tags: windows-phone-8

Here is my code

```
GeoCoordinateWatcher geoWatcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();

geoWatcher.Start();

Geoposition item = new Geoposition();

if (Double.IsNaN(geoWatcher.Position.Location.Altitude))
  item.Altitude = 0;
else
  item.Altitude = geoWatcher.Position.Location.Altitude;

 item.Longitude = geoWatcher.Position.Location.Longitude;
 item.Latitude = geoWatcher.Position.Location.Latitude;
 geoWatcher.Stop();
 GeoCoordinate=new GeoCoordinate(item.Latitude, item.Longitude, item.Altitude);
```

At last line i am getting following exception.

```
 Type ArgumentOutOfRangeException
 ExceptionMessage The value of the parameter must be from -180.0 to 180.0.
 Parameter name  value
```

Why i am getting wrong coordinates?

What is the problem?

Comment: Have you debugged which value is out of range?

Comment: an the values is? maybe you should check for isNaN there too?

Comment: I don't know the value..but if i am passing nan then i didn't get that exception.

Comment: dumb question but how can you tell us that longitude is out of range when you "don't know the value"?

Comment: In stack trace it is given...and i got this exception from users..my application is on live

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32685/discussion-between-user1934329-and-warrenfaith)

Comment: I will not chat, you could at least try the windows-8 chat. Just search for it. Anyway: To make your app at least more robust: check if the value is in range and if not make sure it is. So `if longitude > 180 longitude = 180;`